# What is the difference when generic class is declared with and without using default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a generic class defined down below,
with member parameter an array, i.e. `T grades[5];`

when I declare object of this class, using

```
StudentRecord<int> srInt();
```

and then call a member function of the class, using

```
srInt.setGrades(arrayInt);
```

I get an error,

```
error: request for member ‘setGrades’ in ‘srInt’, which is of non-class type ‘StudentRecord<int>()’
     srInt.setGrades(arrayInt);
```

but when i declare class using(below), and try to call same function, it works

```
StudentRecord<int> srInt;
```

```
//header file for main.cpp

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE=5;

template <class T>
class StudentRecord
{
    private:
        const int size = SIZE;
        T grades[5];
    public:
        void setGrades(T* input);
};

template<class T>
void StudentRecord<T>::setGrades(T* input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE;++i)
    {
        grades[i] = input[i];
    }
}
```

My question is there any difference between declaring class,

```
StudentRecord<int> srInt();
```

v/s

```
StudentRecord<int> srInt;
```

Comment: `StudentRecord<int> srInt();` is a function.

Comment: `StudentRecord<int> srInt();` declares a *function* named `srInt`, which takes no arguments and returns a `StudentRecord<int>` object by value. Drop the parentheses to solve it: StudentRecord<int> srInt;`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Okay, but what is happening behind, like when compiling,

Comment: @Vishal As others have said `StudentRecord<int> srInt();` is a function and `StudentRecord<int> srInt;` is an instance variable.

Comment: @Mat It's not actually the most vexing parse, though it is related.

Comment: You should try to minimise your examples. Templates are not relevant here. You could have removed the template aspect. Then you may have had better luck finding existing answers on this subject.

Comment: when i provide a default value `StudentRecord<int> srInt(-1);` it works then.

Comment: @Vishal That's right.

Comment: what could be the reason?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no "reason", other than that is the syntax you should use to do that thing. That's it.

Comment: `StudentRecord<int> srInt(-1);` is no longer a function declaration. Instead it declares a variable and constructs an object for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not about templates ("generic class").

---

Just like `int f();` is a function declaration, `StudentRecord<int> srInt();`s is a function declaration. Yes, even when you write it in a function.

Remove the `()` and you get an object declaration instead.

That's it!

---

Some people call this the "Most vexing parse", though it is not actually an example of that. It does involve some of the same grammar/language rules to a degree.

When you wrote `StudentRecord<int> srInt(-1);`, that is a valid object declaration, because there is no way it can be a function declaration (`-1` is not an argument declaration).

If `-1` were swapped for a more complex expression, it's possible to get surprised by the fact that it gets interpreted as a valid argument declaration. Like `int f(int());`. *That's* the most vexing parse.

---

There's no magic or strangeness here; you just have to use the right symbols for what you want.